# Non-translatable resources should only be defined in the base values/ folder - Android Export APK

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I get the following error when I try to export my Android project to an APK: Non-translatable resources should only be defined in the base values/ folder.  The here is the code it is having an issue with:

```
<string-array name="about_translators" translatable="false">
```

This is happening in the array.xml file in the values folder in the res directory.  The code it is having an issue with is:

```
translatable="false"
```

How do I fix this issue?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the resources in question are found only in the array.xml file in res/values? Perhaps the same resources (marked translatable="false") are in .xml files in config-specific values folders.

Comment: In Android Studio, push `Ctrl-Shift-F` and type "about_translators" then press enter. This will show you every place that `about_translators` appears in every file in your project.

Answer (score 5):

Just found this problem myself, I had strings marked with `translatable="false"` in a `values-es/strings.xml`. You have to delete them and leave them only on the `values/strings.xml`

Comment: Worked for me, nice solution.